# I can't figure out the meaning of this statement:

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

```
+(AppDelegate*)instance{return [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
```

It's in the middle of an AppDelegate that I am using as a template.  If anyone has time, could you please explain the line or the usefulness of it.

Thank you
Patrick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a utility method:

When in need of an instance of your Application's delegate already casted to the correct class you will call:

```
[AppDelegate instance]
```

instead of:

```
AppDelegate* instance = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
```